# Rubber banding with mouse on model not on screen position

Tags: c#, opengl

I am trying to draw a triangle or rectangle using mouse with Rubberband approach. There are approaches available for Rubber band approach on screen position but i want it on the model position. Can anyone suggest some way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always draw the rubber band in screen space. Once the selection has been performed, transform the rubber band limits into model space planes (the lines of the rubber band translate into a set of 4 planes, that define the selection volume).